# C#/AvaloniaUI - Click a button and change Text

Tags: c#, avaloniaui

I am very new to AvaloniaUI.

I am really struggling to change a text when I click a button.
Here is my code:

```
  <Window xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
          xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
          xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
          xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
          mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="800" d:DesignHeight="450"
          x:Class="ReadyForWar_Launcher.MainWindow"
          Title="ReadyForWar_Launcher">
    <StackPanel>
      <TextBlock Name="TestBlock">Show my text here!</TextBlock>
      <Button Command="{Binding RunTheThing}" CommandParameter="Hello World">Change the Text!</Button>
    </StackPanel>
  </Window>
```

Here is my MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
using Avalonia;
using Avalonia.Controls;
using Avalonia.Markup.Xaml;

namespace ReadyForWar_Launcher
{
    public class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
#if DEBUG
            this.AttachDevTools();
#endif
        }

        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            AvaloniaXamlLoader.Load(this);
        }

        public void RunTheThing()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Inside `RunTheThing` I don't know how can I select the TextBlock with Name="TestBlock" and change the text to "Hello World".

Can you please help me out on this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two approaches, the recommended one and straightforward one.

Recommended: Use MVVM pattern. Create a view model with `ButtonTextProperty` and `RunTheThing` command, make the command to change the property, assign that model to the `DataContext` and bind your button text and command to view model properties. The MVVM approach is basically the same as in WPF, so you can use documentation and tutorials from there (that applies to most of the Avalonia, BTW). For example, here is a [good one](https://intellitect.com/getting-started-model-view-viewmodel-mvvm-pattern-using-windows-presentation-framework-wpf/) (not advertising, 4th link from google).

Straightforward (aka winforms-way): add `x:Name="MyButton"` to your button and use `this.FindControl<Button>("MyButton")` after calling `AvaloniaXamlLoader.Load(this);`. This will give you a `Button` reference that you can manipulate from code. Instead of using commands, you can just subscribe to the click handler directly from codebehind, add `public void MyButton_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args){}` to your `MainWindow` class and add replace Command and CommandParameter with `Click="MyButton_OnClick"`. That way button click will trigger your event handler.

Note, that the second approach doesn't scale well with the application size and suffers from code complexity when handling lists.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. However, Avalonia seems not to allow using `Click="MyButton_OnClick"` The `Click` is not allowed anymore I think. Can you please make a more detailed answer on the first approach?

Comment: The Click event [does exist](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/blob/ccb4b938ec6a2d774d01efc85f871a9e2d4e95b0/src/Avalonia.Controls/Button.cs#L100) in the Button class. Make sure that event handler signature is matching and the handler is public.

Comment: First approach example - https://gist.github.com/kekekeks/4895195222eed65add7d39da771cb0f2

Comment: I will try it! Thank you. Can you please try out one example with `Click=""` method ? I was receiving errors when I was trying to work out that method ?

Comment: `<Button Click="MyButton_Click">Test</Button>` and    `public void MyButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args) =>  ((Button) sender).Content = "New text";` in `MainWindow.xaml.cs` works for me

Comment: When I add `Click="MyButton_Click"` I am receiving the following error:`Unable to find suitable setter or adder for property Click of type Avalonia.Controls:Avalonia.Controls.Button for argument System.Private.CoreLib:System.String, available setter parameter lists are:
System.EventHandler`1[[Avalonia.Interactivity.RoutedEventArgs, Avalonia.Interactivity, Version=0.9.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] ....`

Why Am I receiving this error ?

Comment: I've been attempting to port WPF code to Avalonia in the past week, and no, at least using the 0.9.0 extension for Visual Studio(2017), the Click event results in the same error as VenelinVasilev @kekekeks

Comment: That error is usually caused by mismatched event handler signature, it means that compiler can't find a handler of type `EventHandler<RoutedEventArgs>`, so conversion fails. Your event handler method should be *exactly* `public void MyButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)`.

Comment: Why the hell I need to use "MVVM pattern" instead of Straightforward one? Is it some crazy joke - to use the most difficult solution, because someone recommend it? Straightforward approach allow to implement whatever you want with just a single line, while MVVM needs creating separate class

Comment: @kekekeks your example helped me so thanks buddy